# Monitor HDMI compatibility

Tags: hdmi

Is this LG ultrawide monitor hdmi entry fully compatible with raspberry pi 3 model b?

http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-25UM58-P-ultrawide-monitor

I ask because monitor's hdmi if of type 2.0 and raspberry's 1.4 (full size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use that exact display with my Raspberry Pi 3B Jessie.  No problems.

It also works in dual input mode with Pi on one side and my MacMini display port on the other, since the display is so wide.

Comment: Thank you very much! And are tou able to run with monitor's full resolution or full HD? (and no hdmi problems, right?)

Comment: Just plug abd play , then?

Comment: I use the dual mode 99% of the time which puts 1920x1080 on one side.  I was not able to figure out how to get hdmi_cvt 2560 1080 60 7 0 0 0  to show up as DMT 87.

Answer (score 1):

The max definition of the RPI is 1920x1080 px

Comment: So it is not possible to use?

Comment: @user122024 that is not what you asked? You asked if it was fully compatable. Most monitors with DVI or HDMI inputs will work. I don't think the differing HDMI versions will present an issue.

Comment: And the max resolution issue? Does that simply means raspberry will not take advantage of monitor's full resolution or does that mean image won't work?